# DocuSign Rest API login issue

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I get JSON response {"errorCode": "USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT",  "message": "The specified User is not a member of the specified Account."} when we deployed application on a new SF sandbox with a different DocuSign account. Obviously I have changed the user/password and integration key for the new account. And after I make token request I get access token back, but I can not make post request due to above.
Can you guys help me understand why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users who want to send documents need a DocuSign account.  It sounds like you've changed the username and password credentials however it is still pointing to the previous account hence the error.  To resolve you need to update the integration to point to the new account.